# Laravel 5.2 different validation rules based on another field value inside request class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish, I have a form that has a dropdown field of types, lets say `type1, type2, type3`, and I have a textfield, I want to make the `rule` for the textfield depend on the type, for example if the type is `type1` then the validation `rule` for the value of the textfield should be `'email'` if it is `type2` then the validation rule is `'number'`, etc.
I have read the Validation documentation on the Laravel site, I know [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) is what I'm trying to accomplish, but I like to keep validation logic separate from the controller, and it doesn't say how to call the `sometimes` method from within the request class.

Comment: If you want to keep the validation logic separated from the controller use this trait https://github.com/dwightwatson/validating

Comment: Go for custom validation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules